# pre sort large vector by multiple keys and store mapping

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, mapping

i have a larg std::vector  of a custom particle object with multiple keys. It' can be few 100 MB large containing 50-250k particles.

I want to be able to plot these particles by different attributes eg:

```
particle[p].kin_energy / particle[p].mass / particle[p].comet
```

...somthing along those lines. And i need to sort by these keys. Part of my application is plotting these particles after the calculations are over. But sorting theses large vectors on the fly can take up 15sek(that is to long). And saving multiple presorted vectors by different keys takes up to much ram.

Is there a way to map different orders to the same vector? Something like this?

```
pair<position_ordered_by_mass;position_in_original_vector> mass_mapping;
```

So i can keep one vector with all the particles, and use mass_mapping to find the particle that would be next to plot by iterating over position_ordered_by_mass.

Is there a container that does that or an efficient approach to doing this?

I had a look at boost::mulimap std::map and some other things but i didn't really find what i was looking for.

cheers

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your particle object is quite heavy (~420 bytes), so instead you can heave multiple different pre-sorted array that only store an index that point to your main vector storing particles.

`unsigned int` can be used to index all those 250k elements.
If my math is correct they're only going to be about 7MB each.

Keep in mind though, that because access pattern to your main array is going to be non-local (you going to jump between different indices that are far away from each other), it will lead to a lot of cache misses and can make it quite slow.

Comment: Thx for the answer, i will try that approach and see if that provides enough performance. Didn't know about cache misses -> good to know :)

Answer (score 0):

This approach worked fine for me. I got the time to load an unsorted vector to a new sorted vector from around 15sek to something about 35ms with additionally multithreading(duo core) the load process. 428x faster. Thx for the help.